# Google Tag Manager - Tag Firing Way too Many Times

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, eventtrigger, event-tracking

We are having an issue with our tracking on www.x3tradesmen.com where a Google Tag Manager tag is firing way too many times and we cannot determine why...

We only have one website event tag linked to Google Analytics called Form Submit and typically we would receive between 2-10 Form Submit events per day at the most, however, recently we have noticed that the tag is firing 1000's of times sporadically and we cannot pinpoint the issue. We have also noticed that our users have drastically increased for short time periods (minutes/hours). We typically only get 40-80 users per day on our website but we saw a massive spike of around 400 users in less than one hour once.

We recently added the facebook pixel via GTM and that is really the only change that we have made and now we are seeing these issues. Does anyone know of any common reasons to why this would be behaving this way or can anyone see any major issues with our implementation of GA or GTM on our website that would cause this?

I know this information is vague, so please let me know if there is specific information that would help identify the issue.

Thanks in advance!

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcvrv.png)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aA9ua.png)

[Screenshot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbT3K.png)

[Screenshot 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wvr0C.png)

[Screenshot 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLs5d.png)

Answer (score 1):

I presume it is the FB pixel - Facebook automatically collects information in addition to what you have configured yourself and uses post/submit events to send them. You can disable that behaviour [as per documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-websites/pixel-events/v2.12) and see if it makes a difference:

> Automatic Configuration
>
> The Facebook pixel will send button click and
>   page metadata (such as data structured according to Opengraph or
>   Schema.org formats) from your website to improve your ads delivery and
>   measurement and automate your pixel setup. To configure the Facebook
>   Pixel to not send this additional information, in the Facebook Pixel
>   Base code, add fbq('set', 'autoConfig', 'false', '')
>   above the init call.

I had a similar issue where suddenly additional submit events turned up in the GTM preview pane that I finally tracked down to FB, so there is a good chance that yours is the same problem.

Comment: thank you very much! I installed the Facebook Pixel via GTM the other day so that helps narrow it down a ton!! I know that this is probably a stupid question but I am not sure where to but the code within the Facebook Pixel Tag... Could you possibly guide me where to put the code within the Pixel Base Code below?

Comment: `<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
  !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
  {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
  n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
  if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
  n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
  t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
  'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
  fbq('init', '123456789');
</script>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
`

Comment: Not a stupid question, but mentioned in the quoted documentation :-) Goes above the line with the init call (i.e. above your last line in your code snippet).

Comment: Unfortunately I have followed the instructions to stop Facebook from sending additional Microdata, however, it has not solved my issue... The event tag for both GTM and Facebook Pixel Event is still firing an exceptional amount of times... Does anyone have any additional thoughts on why this behavior is happening?

Comment: My first thought is that you should not accept an answer before you have confirmed that it is actually helpful (you can un-accept, though). Is there any chance that you can share an url where we can have a look at the problem ?

Comment: My apologies... Our website is https://www.x3tradesmen.com. I do not have a specific page that it happens on because it happens on every page of our website sporadically.

Comment: Based off of looking at the events on GA, it seems to happen even on pages that don't have forms which is odd because the trigger should not fire at all since there is no form on the page. Most of the time the trigger/tag fires only one time perfectly fine, but on occasion, it seems like the page gets stuck loading and both the GTM Form Submit tag fires and the Facebook Pixel Event Tag and it rapidly fires the tag until I close out the page. I have only been able to reproduce the issue twice while using GTM preview.

Comment: I have added some screenshots in the original post that may be of some assistance in explaining...